# Create an XSL stylesheet to omit unwanted elements based on input parameters

Tags: xml, xslt

This is going to be a bit long and specific so please bear with me.  I understand how XSLT works but I don't know all of the elements that do the operations.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Lets say I have a pilot manual for 737s written in XML.  However, there are 3 types of 737s (400, 600, and 800) and although 90% of the manual is the same for all three types there are specific parts that are only for each type.  Some pilots will only ever learn about 1 or 2 (or sometimes all 3) jets so I'd like to omit the sections that aren't relevant for them.  Here's how I have the XML set up:

```
<manual>
    <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
    <section t600="no" t800="no">B: This is relevant only for the 737-400</section>
    <section t800="no">C: This is relevant for 737-400 and 737-600</section>
    <section t400="no">D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

I want to be able to specify, somehow, that I'm only interestd in, say, the 737-800 and get a manual like this:

```
<manual>
    <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
    <section>D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

Or for a different pilot that is interested in two jets, say the 737-400 and 737-600, the manual would look like this:

```
<manual>
    <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
    <section>B: This is relevant only for the 737-400</section>
    <section>C: This is relevant for 737-400 and 737-600</section>
    <section>D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

I have access to the source XML so if the way I've set it up doesn't make sense I can change it.  My thinking was since almost everything is the same for all types it makes more sense to opt-out, but I realize it might make it harder to match?  I'm not sure.

Thanks again for taking a look!  Let me know if I've left something out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pInterests">
  <interest topic="t800"/>
 </xsl:param>


 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "section[some $t in $pInterests/*/@topic
            satisfies
              not($t = current()/@*[. eq 'no']/name())
          ]
  ">
   <section><xsl:apply-templates/></section>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<manual>
    <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
    <section t600="no" t800="no">B: This is relevant only for the 737-400</section>
    <section t800="no">C: This is relevant for 737-400 and 737-600</section>
    <section t400="no">D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<manual>
   <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
   <section>D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

**If we replace in the transformation the current parameter**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pInterests">
  <interest topic="t800"/>
 </xsl:param>
```

**with**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pInterests">
  <interest topic="t400"/>
  <interest topic="t600"/>
 </xsl:param>
```

**and apply the modified transformation on the same XML document again, we also get the wanted and correct result**:

```
<manual>
   <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
   <section>B: This is relevant only for the 737-400</section>
   <section>C: This is relevant for 737-400 and 737-600</section>
   <section>D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pInterests">
  <interest topic="t800"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:key name="kSectionTypeAttrByName" match="section/@*"
  use="concat(generate-id(..),'|', name())"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vInterests" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pInterests']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:variable name="vSec" select="."/>

  <xsl:variable name="vHasInterest">
   <xsl:for-each select="$vInterests/@topic">
    <xsl:variable name="vTopic" select="."/>


    <xsl:for-each select=
     "$vSec[not(key('kSectionTypeAttrByName',
                    concat(generate-id(),'|', $vTopic)
                   )
                =
                 'no'
                )
           ]">
      <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:if test="string($vHasInterest)">
   <section><xsl:apply-templates/></section>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<manual>
    <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
    <section t600="no" t800="no">B: This is relevant only for the 737-400</section>
    <section t800="no">C: This is relevant for 737-400 and 737-600</section>
    <section t400="no">D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<manual>
   <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
   <section>D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

**If we replace in the transformation the current parameter**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pInterests">
  <interest topic="t800"/>
 </xsl:param>
```

**with**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pInterests">
  <interest topic="t400"/>
  <interest topic="t600"/>
 </xsl:param>
```

**and apply the modified transformation on the same XML document again, we also get the wanted and correct result**:

```
<manual>
   <section>A: This is relevant for every type</section>
   <section>B: This is relevant only for the 737-400</section>
   <section>C: This is relevant for 737-400 and 737-600</section>
   <section>D: This is relevant for 737-600 and 737-800</section>
</manual>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help and examples but I couldn't get it working.  I'm using the xslt task in ant using java6 with no additional libraries. For the XSLT2 solution I'm getting a syntax error on the main expression: "Error parsing XPath expression 'section[some ...'".  For the XSLT1 solution I'm getting what appears to be a runtime error: "Error checking type of the expression 'filter-expr(variable-ref(vSec/node-type), [pred(funcall(not, [=(funcall(key, [literal-expr(kSectionTypeAttrByName), ...".  I've used ant for xslt (2.0) in the past so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @rjcarr: I have run successfully my transformations: the XSLT 2.0 one with: Saxon 9.1.5; The XSLT 1.0 one with: MSXML 3/4, .NET XslCompiledTransform and .NET XslTransform, AltovaXML (XML-SPY), Saxon 6.5.4. You definitely are using a buggy XSLT processor -- I didn't understand what XSLT processor(s) you are using?

Comment: I'm using whatever processors come with the java6 jdk.  I will try your processors and then try to get updated processors for my (java) environment.  Thanks again for the help and please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I replaced the standard processor (xalan, I think) with the saxon processor and it worked as you described.  Thanks for the tip and thanks for the help! I'll mark your answer as the solution.